# htaccess redirect, assist please

Tags: url-rewrite, https, htaccess, http-request, redirect-url

What i am trying to do is rewrite some URLs and apply SSL on certaing pages on my site.

This is the code that i have:

```
  RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^mylogin$ index.php?view=login [QSA,L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^registerme$ index.php?view=register [QSA,L,NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(mylogin|registerme)/?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC]
```

This works to the extent that:
I am able to access `http(s)://example.com/mylogin` both. Also `http(s)://example.com/index.php?view=login` is still available. My goal is to have only one active URL `https://example.com/mylogin` .

Another thing is that i have a lot of pages on my site tied to index.php. What i would like to do is when someone opens `http://example.com` to go to `https://example.com`.

I also have rewites for the pages that i need to force them to http://

```
RewriteRule ^viewpr$     index.php?view=products  [QSA,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^wall$       wall.php                  [QSA,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^services$   services.php              [QSA,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^exchange$  exp_exchange.php?view=exp       [QSA,L,NC]
```

So to summarize i need `https://example.com` , `https://example.com/mylogin` and `https://example.com/registerme`, and i need only those options available.

For the rewrites on the bottom same thing but on http:// . Honestly i dont care about the other URLs. Please advice.